# How to call a function within a function in Lua?

Tags: function, lua, nested-function

I have this code:

```
function test()
    function awesome()
        print("im awesome!")
    end

    function notawesome()
        print("im not awesome.")
    end

    function notevenawesome()
        print("im not even awesome...")
    end
end

test().notawesome()
```

When I run this, the console prints

> 15: attempt to index a nil value

What I'm trying to do is call the function **notawesome()** within the function **test()**, how would I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything (thus returning nil). Something like this should work:

```
function test()
    function awesome()
        print("im awesome!")
    end

    function notawesome()
        print("im not awesome.")
    end

    function notevenawesome()
        print("im not even awesome...")
    end
    result = {}
    result["notawesome"] = notawesome
    result["awesome"] = awesome
    result["notevenawesome"] = notevenawesome
    return result
end
test().notawesome()
```

Comment: Why is it that code like this doesnt need a return `function test() print("blah") end test()` ?

Comment: Your function doesn't *need* a return either, it's also returning nil. However, If you want to access some stuff defined inside of your function you need to return it.

Comment: @lhf mentioned variable scope in a comment on my answer. This answer could be improved by making the variables `awesome`, `notawesome`, `notevenawesome` local since they are not used outside of the `test` function. `test` could also be made local but that would depend on the design.

Answer (score 5):

@Axnyff [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600983/2226988) what you might be trying to do. I'll explain what you did.

If you are familiar with other languages, please note that Lua does not have function *declarations*; It has function *definitions*, which are expressions that produce a function value when evaluated. Function definition statements, which you have used, are just shortcuts that implicitly include an assignment. See the manual.

When you run your code, a function definition is evaluated and the resulting function value is assigned to the variable `test`. Then the variable `test` is evaluated and its value is called as a function (and it is one).

When that function executes, three function definitions are evaluated and assigned to the variables `awesome`, `notawesome`, and `notevenawesome`, repsectively. It doesn't return anything.

So, when the result of calling `test` (`nil`) is indexed by the string "awesome", you get the error.

If you wanted to call the function value referred by the variable `awesome`, just do `awesome()`.

Comment: Also, `awesome`, `notawesome`, `notevenawesome` are *global* variables.

Comment: @lhf Yes, I considered saying that all the variables are global. However, the code does the same thing even if the variables are local (which, in that case _and_ given the syntax used, would be confusing enough to be considered bad style).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that instead to use the main function you can use an object:

```
test = {
    awesome = (function()
        return 'im awesome!'
    end),
    notawesome = (function()
        return 'im not awesome.'
    end),
    notevenawesome = (function()
        return 'im not even awesome...'
    end)
}
```

To call your functions use this:

```
print(test.notawesome())    --> im not awesome.
```